I can not install a new custom indicator to Tradingview because the paste function does not appearin the drop down menu fix this problem?
How do I fix the following problem? I am adding a new custom indicator to Tradingview by going to Pine editor, add new indicator, open but there is no paste option in the drop down menu to paste the new script.
I am adding a new custom indicator to Tradingview by going to Pine editor, add new indicator, open but there is no paste option in the drop down menu to paste the new script.
